# WordPress + &shy;?

Tags: wordpress, html-entities

In one of my projects it's important that hyphenation can get controlled with `&shy;`

Unfortunately WordPress removes that html entity if I enter it in the "text" view of the text editor. How could I achieve that WordPress doesn't remove it?

Answer (score 2):

shyBy default, most HTML gets removed from the copy in the TinyMCE editor. You can prevent that by adding this to the functions.php file of your active theme.

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
    $opts = 'shy';
    $initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

I revised my answer to change filter from catching all html to just the shy entity, based on my findings [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/correct-way-to-allow-nbsp-entity-in-tinymce) and [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration). See if that works.

If not then try this:

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
    $initArray['entities'] = 'shy'; 
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

Comment: Thanks! And what would I have to specify to only allow & shy ;? I don't want to allow all tags.

Comment: That would require some more research. But here is a pretty good lead for you. [LINK](http://wpengineer.com/1963/customize-wordpress-wysiwyg-editor/)

Comment: I did some research... Your solution only seems to be for tags. But & shy ; is no tag. So I am pretty stuck. :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that you are stuck. Let me clarify. Yes, the link referenced in my comment refers to the filtering of HTML tags. My solution here excludes the filter from processing all HTML in the editor (entities included). So the reference was to demonstrate that there are means for targeting specific HTML elements using the filter. But I have yet to find a filter that will let you specify HTML entities for exclusion. If you find something like that, I would be interested in taking a look at it.

Comment: hm... no, I didn't get your solutions to work. Always if a change from text view to wysiwyg view, the shy vanishes. But I found a different simple solution: add_shortcode('shy', 'my_shy_shortcode'); function my_shy_shortcode($atts) {return '&shy;';} :)

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't have thought to do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

my soft hyphens seem to be working although they are invisible in text-editor. This seems to be intended behaviour: [Post Editor Automatically Deletes Soft Hyphens](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32744)